# npm "validator" vs "express-validator"

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to Node JS and haven't used any of these modules. Can I please ask for help on which of these two validators is better and more efficient to use?

validator:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

express-validator:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are used for different scenarios:

- `validator` is a library to validate any kind of object and it's not associated with any framework.
- `express-validator` uses `validator` library to validate `expressjs` routes. Basically you can validate express routes out of the box using validator lib.

In my honest opinion you can easily create your own validator middleware. Specially if you are new to Node.js it will help you to understand how middlewares work. If you are not interested on that and you have an `express` application feel free to use `express-validator`

Also I really recommend JOI as a validator lib https://github.com/hapijs/joi it's simple and it works well.

Here is an example of a middleware (I have not tested)

```
const Joi = require('joi')
module.exports = function validate(joiSchema) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    const result = Joi.validate(req.body, joiSchema, {
      allowUnknown: true,
      abortEarly: false
    })

    if (result.error) {
      throw new result.error
    }

    await next()
  }
}

  // express route
  router.post(
    '/create',
    validateMiddleware({
      body: {
        body: { firstName: Joi.string(), lastName: Joi.string() }
      }
    }),
    (req, res, next) => {
    // your logic
   })
```

Comment: Hi, @Marco, thank you for your feedback. I see. how about the ease of implementation on different scenarios and performance issues? Is it better to use the basic validator library?

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you an exemple how to implement your validation middleware using Joi. Read this: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html if you want to understand the middleware concept, it's going to help you in the future for other kind of middlewares (authentication/logging/caching).

Comment: It's up to you if you don't want to "reinvent the wheel" use `express-validator` or https://github.com/continuationlabs/celebrate it's  a well tested validators and it will work if you want to validate your express routes.

Comment: I see. I will read all of your suggestions and study them. Thank you so much for your help @Marco

Answer (score 0):

Express-validator is used as middleware, the idea with express-validator is to check bad input before it reaches your controller.

Now, if you are using validator, you can make your own validation function in which you will simply pass the data and it will tell if the input is in accordance to it (Just like checking an Email, here you can have a function, which will check if input given to it is a function or not).

In case you are using Services in your structure, then you can use validator as I feel it's easy and of more control than express-validator